# Взаимодействие между двумя UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Доброго всем дня!
Имеется такой вопрос:
Создано главное Окно на WPF, отдельно в этом же пространстве имен создается два UserControlа и помещаются на окно, при этом обработчик событий вынесен в отдельный классов соответствии с патерном MVVM и эти два контрола ссылаются на этот класс, но при компиляции получается что они создают два отдельных объекта этого класса, никак не связанных с друг другом и взаимодействия между ними никак не получается....подскажите что делать..
Спасибо!

Comment: @Alex_student, уточните, какого рода взаимодействие предполагается между этими контролами? И ещё: их всегда будет два или в будущем их может стать больше?

Comment: Эээ... Какой обработчик событий? Это вы так называете VM? У каждого контрола обычно своя личная VM, вот эти экземпляры пусть между собой и коммуницируют.

Answer (score 1):

Ex. : `this.userC1.DataContext = this.userC2.DataContext = DataContext = mainVM;` 
В конструкторе главного окна и у вас будет один объект.

Answer (score 0):

[Using Mediator to communicate between user controls](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/using-mediator-to-communicate-between-user-controls-part-1/)